# How to externalise data.sql for a spring boot app

Tags: database, spring, spring-boot, h2, configuration-files

I always use **data.sql** file in my resource folder if I want to initialise my H2 database with spring boot.

Now I need to use a H2 database but also to externalise **data.sql** in order to update this file when there are any changes.

I don't want to install MySql or other Databases because it's a very small service with a few database items and this service may be restarted sometimes.

So I have my folder in which there are the following two files:  the **uber jar** file of my spring boot application (with **Tomcat** embedded) and **data.sql** file.

How can I externalise **data.sql** like the way I can externalise the configurations for **application.properties**?

Answer (score 0):

How about putting it in the classpath when you run the jar?

```
java -jar uber.jar -classpath "PATH_TO_YOUR_SQL_FILE"
```

Comment: if my data.sql is in the same folder of the uber jar is it: -classpath "data.sql"?

Comment: Yes. In second thought, I dont know if it's going to work, because maybe the "-classpath" overrides the classpath that the jar declared in his manifest file.
Please let me know if it works or not

Comment: thank you, it doesn't work. I'm trying to find new solution. Still it seems strange not to be possible to externalise data.sql.